# Why Should I Write Unit Tests if I have UI Automation Tests

Tags: unit-testing, ui-automation

If I have UI automation tests, why do I need to write unit tests?

If I need to check that a method returns some output for a given input, for example a result of an addition which is then displayed in a view, why do I need unit test if I can confirm that output in the view is correct (or not correct) through UI automation test

Comment: This question is more suited to the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) community than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FaheelAhmad over there it would probably be closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/204786/31260) (and maybe additionally voted down for the lack of reasearch)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unit test and end to end test (UI tests) have two different purposes

- Unit test tell you when unit of code (module, class, function, interface) has an issue
- End to end tests tell you how that failure affects end to end output.

Lets use an analogy to understand why we need both.

Suppose you were manufacturing a car by assembling different components like carburettor, gear box, tyres, crankshaft etc. All these parts are being made by different vendors(think developers).

When car fails to work as expected, will you need to test individual components to figure out where the problem originates from ?

Will testing components before assembling the car, make you save time and effort ?

Typically what you want to do is to make sure each component work as expected (unit tests) before you add them to your car.

When the car does not work as expected, you test each component to find the root cause of the problem.

This typically works by creating an assembly line (CI pipeline). Your testing strategy looks like

1. test individual components
2. test if they work when interfaced with other components
3. test the car once all components are assembled together.

This testing strategy is what we call a testing pyramid in programming.

Reading this might give you more insight : https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html

Comment: Thanks.  This all makes sense, I understand what these tests are and how they work.  But I have been hearing from coworkers and also starting to believe myself, that unit tests are more of a waste of time if same test is covered by say calabash (https://calaba.sh/) which gives great documentation and can validate expect outcome(s) in a feature test.  But I think I see your point, I guess you are saying, "if car fails, how do you know it was crankshaft that caused it to fail?".  With unit test, you know "crankshaft failed, therefore, car will fail too"  Thanks

Comment: Yes, and apart from that, it also documents what crankshaft is expected to do as a unit, for e.g. "it should work 1000RPM" etc. When car fails to work with a new engine and we figure out that crankshaft fails at RPM of 1200, we update tests for crankshaft to make sure it works at 1200RPM (and then fix the unit).

Answer (score 5):

Two reasons immediately come to mind as to why you would want unit tests despite having automation tests.

1. Unit tests make ruthless code refactoring a much less daunting challenge, and mitigate that risk
2. Unit tests provide invaluable documentation of the code, what each module does (automation tests don't give you this), when the code changes the unit tests change also unlike stale documentation in some wiki or doc that never gets updated later as code continues to change and evolve over time.

Comment: Hi and thanks.  But looking at Calabash UI Automation testing for example, it gives you even better documentation I would say.  Isn't it so, take a look, in fact, you get documentation in plain english https://calaba.sh/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Nishants and James' answers: With UI/End-to-End tests it is much harder to test for certain error conditions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to understand that unit test cases and user interface  (UI) test automation are two different concepts. In unit test cases, you write test cases per unit and test them module by module---you're actually testing each module separately.

[Test automation](https://www.perfecto.io/blog/what-is-test-automation), on the other hand, covers end-to-end testing. It tests your end-to-end inputs and their respective outputs. Both have their own advantages, so you need to use both on your product to make sure it is bug-free. Let's better understand the need for unit tests with the help of an example:

You're building a chatting app. For the app, you're integrating different modules like login, registration, send and receive a message, message history etc. Now, suppose there are multiple developers working on this product:  each developer has worked on a different module. In this scenario, you need to join all the modules into the system flow to make the complete product. When you integrate all the modules,  you find  that the product is not able to store messages. So, now you need to test each module independently because you can't tell  which specific module didn't work.

To avoid such cases, it's better to test each module before merging it  with the others.  This is called [unit testing](https://www.guru99.com/unit-testing-guide.html). If unit testing is done correctly, you will get the bug immediately. Once all the unit test cases pass, you can finally start integrating modules.

Unit testing  is generally executed  through the use of an assembly line  ([CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)). Your product usually works if you create a good testing strategy and write the best test cases. The flow is a bit like this:

- Test individual modules
- Start integrating and testing each functionality and see if it's working or not
- Run UI automation test cases on the product once you have integrated all the modules

In the end, if all test cases  pass,  that means your system is ready to work flawlessly.